# Testing the new Google reCAPTCHA v3

Tags: testing, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

What are the best ways to test failures? I know of the UserAgent change trick where setting it to "Googlebot" for example, will fail the test.

However are there other ways to test this?

I can test how my application will behave when the score is below the acceptable threshold but I would like to simulate a bot (in the eyes of Google) in the browser in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, that this is what you are looking for, but you can try to issue duplicate request to your back-end endpoint with the same `g-recaptcha-response` parameter, you have already used in any previous request.

When you call the back-end for the first time you will get valid response from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

```
{"success":true,"score":0.9,"action":"register","challenge_ts":"2020-07-21T18:09:09Z","hostname":"localhost"}
```

After calling the same endpoint for the second time with the same `g-recaptcha-response` parameter, google API will respond with something like this:

```
{"success":false,"score":0.0,"error-codes":["TimeoutOrDuplicate"]}
```

Answer (score -1):

On desktop or phone using Chrome Incognito mode will get you a low score of 0.1 ~ 0.3 (in my case, at least). See here: https://tehnoblog.org/google-no-captcha-invisible-recaptcha-first-experience-results-review/#google-invisible-recaptcha-v3.0-live-demo

Comment: I get 0.9 using Incognito or trying to emulate GoogleBot 2.1 in developer tools.  Any ideas?

Comment: @KBr I've also encountered this. Using incognito AND Googlebot user agent still results in a pass. Did you find an alternative?